# Confused about translating function to account for data abstraction

Tags: python, arrays, string, abstraction, abstract-data-type

Currently working on a function, whose description is here:

[image: Description of problem]

Here are the provided accessor and data abstraction functions

```
def word_time(word, elapsed_time):
    """A data abstrction for the elapsed time that a player finished a word."""
    return [word, elapsed_time]


def word(word_time):
    """An accessor function for the word of a word_time."""
    return word_time[0]


def elapsed_time(word_time):
    """An accessor function for the elapsed time of a word_time."""
    return word_time[1]
```

And the function I coded that doesnt account for data abstraction:

```
def fastest_words(word_times, margin=1e-5):
    """A list of which words each player typed fastest."""
    n_players = len(word_times)
    n_words = len(word_times[0]) - 1
    assert all(len(times) == n_words + 1 for times in word_times)
    assert margin > 0
    # BEGIN PROBLEM 9
    maxScore = 1000000
    winner = -1
    playersResults = []

    for i in range(n_players):
        playersResults.append([])

    for x in range(n_words):
        bestScore = float ('inf')
        for y in range(n_players):
            timePassed = word_times[y][x+1][1] - word_times[y][x][1]
            if timePassed < bestScore:
                bestScore = timePassed 
                winner = y 
        for z in range(n_players):
            elapsed = word_times[z][x+1][1] - word_times[z][x][1] 
            if elapsed - bestScore <= margin:
                playersResults[z].append(word_times[z][x+1][0])
    return playersResults
```

I tried to translate it to have data abstraction, but it's not working, and I don't know why?

```
def fastest_words(word_times, margin=1e-5):
    """A list of which words each player typed fastest."""
    n_players = len(word_times)
    n_words = len(word_times[0]) - 1
    assert all(len(times) == n_words + 1 for times in word_times)
    assert margin > 0
    # BEGIN PROBLEM 9
    maxScore = 1000000
    winner = -1
    playersResults = []

    for i in range(n_players):
        playersResults.append([])
    tempComparison = 0
    tempElapsed = 0
    for times in word_times:
        bestScore = float ('inf')
        for y in range(n_players):
            timePassed= elapsed_time(times[y]) - tempComparison
            tempComparison = timePassed
            if timePassed < bestScore:
                bestScore = timePassed 
                winner = y 
        for z in range(n_players):
            elapsed =  elapsed_time(times[y]) - tempElapsed
            tempElapsed = elapsed
            if elapsed - bestScore <= margin:
                playersResults[z].append(word(times))

    return playersResults
```

But I'm really confused on how to do this?

Comment: Your loops are different in the two versions. In the first version, the outer loop is over word indexes, but in the second version the outer loop is over players in `word_times`.

Comment: How do I change that while using data abstraction?

Comment: What does data abstraction have to do with the loop structure? Abstraction just means that you change `xxx[0]` and `xxx[1]` to `word(xxx)` and `elapsed_time(xxx)` when `xxx` is a `word_times` value.